# Can not able establish platform event connection through workbench

Tags: platform-event

In our org we have defined list of platform events and we can able to view payload through workbench under generic subscription. But, after Salesforce critical update to remove instance number from the domain URL is activated, Workbench generic subscription is throwing handshake unsuccessful error and 403 error. With Salesforce critical update activation we can not able to view platform events payload under workbench whether payload get generated from Salesforce or not. Any thoughts on work around or tool that I can use to view/refer payload generated from Salesforce.? Thanks in advance.

[image]